# Put <a> at bottom of parent element <p>

Tags: html, css

I believe this is a simple fix but so far I can't find it.

(Consider the screenshots below)

I have a `<a class="addcomment">` within a `<p>` and I simply want the `<a>` to always be on the bottom left of the `<p>`, no matter its height.

Using
`position: relative; left: 0px; bottom: 0px;` doesn't do the job even though I am sure that the `<p>` is the parent of the `<a>`.

This is the current CSS styling for the element:

```
a.addcomment:link,
a.addcomment:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #820106;
  color: #820106;
}

a.addcomment:hover,
a.addcomment:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  color: #820106;
}
```

[this looks good because the a tag is at the bottom anyways](http://captainscall.site11.com/temp_stuff/a-tag-1.png)

[this does not because the a tag is not at the bottom where I want it](http://captainscall.site11.com/temp_stuff/a-tag-2.png)

Thank you for knowledge and suggestions in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give the `position:relative` to the p, and the a with `position absolute; bottom:0; left:0`

Answer (score 1):

you can try a min-height for the "P" element.